# Sheet print WITH DDE link

Tags: excel, vba

i'm not knowledgable with excel macros but would like to know how to write a script to print the active sheet when a single cell's value changes from a 0 to a 1 . i'm currently using a DDE LINK between a scada system and excel and i'd like to have this print every time i close a bit in the plc program so that it can be attached to the bach

Answer (score 0):

Put the active sheet printing code in Worksheet_Change event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Address
    ActiveSheet.PrintOut
End Sub
```